# Memoizing an entire block in Python

Tags: python, memoization, joblib

Say I have some code that creates several variables:

```
# Some code

# Beginning of the block to memoize
a = foo()
b = bar()
...
c =
# End of the block to memoize

# ... some more code
```

I would like to **memoize** the entire block above without having to be explicit about every variable created/changed in the block or pickle them manually. How can I do this in Python?

Ideally I would like to be able to wrap it with something (`if/else` or `with` statement) and have a flag that forces a refresh if I want.

**Conceptually** speaking, it woul dbe like:

```
# Some code

# Flag that I can set from outside to save or force a reset of the chache 
refresh_cache = True

if refresh_cache == False
   load_cache_of_block()
else:      
   # Beginning of the block to memoize
   a = foo()
   b = bar()
   ...
   c = stuff()
   # End of the block to memoize

   save_cache_of_block()

# ... some more code
```

Is there any way to do this without having to explicitly pickle each variable defined or changed in the code? (i.e. at the end of the first run we save, and we later just reuse the values)

Comment: I don't think there's any sane way to do that for the values of local variables.  However, you could create a cache object and do all your calculations with `cache.a = foo()`, etc., then reuse the cache object.

Comment: You could just wrap it into a (locally defined) function, if it's okay to do `a, b, c = block()`

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k Wouldn't that require being explicit about the variables created/changed in the block? (i.e. at a minimum you have to pull them out from the function, i.e. type their names, etc)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to go about this but I think the way that's closest to what you're describing would be to use pythons `module scope` as your memoized  and `import` or `reload` as needed. Something like this:

```
# a.py
import b

print b.a, b.b
b.func(5)
b.b = 'world'
print b.a, b.b

if b.needs_refresh():
    reload(b)

print b.a, b.b
```

With your "variable scope" being the module `b`:

```
# b.py
a = 0
b = 'hello'

def func(i):
    global a
    a += i

def needs_refresh():
    return a >= 5
```

Executing this results in what you'd expect:

```
 0 hello
 5 world
 0 hello
```

Edit: to be allow you to copy and save the entire scope you could just use a class scope:

```
 memo_stack = list()

 class MemoScope(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = 0
         self.b = 'hello'

 memo = MemoScope()
 memo.a = 2
 memo.b = 3

 memo_stack.append(memo)
 memo_stack.append(MemoScope())

 for i, o in enumerate(memo_stack):
     print "memo t%i.a = %s" % (i, o.a)
     print "memo t%i.b = %s" % (i, o.b)
     if o.a == 2:
         memo_stack[i] = MemoScope()
         print "refreshed"

# memo t0.a = 2
# memo t0.b = 3
# refreshed
# memo t1.a = 0
# memo t1.b = hello
```

Comment: Doesn't this always reset to `0 hello` ?  AKA: you can't store an intermediate state? example: t0 a = 0, t1 a = 1, t2 a = 2, but we want to refresh to state at t1 (the last stored/memoized state).

Comment: Absolutely, you can't copy the module AFAIK, but if that's what you want then like mentioned above @BrenBarn, use a class/instance scope: answer updated.

Comment: It's probably what the OP wants, because in memoization problems you almost certainly want intermediate state (though the OP might be misusing the term).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `locals()` to get a list of the local variables, storing them in a dict in pickle, then using (below is more conceptual):

```
for k,v in vars_from_pickle:
  run_string = '%s=%s' % (k,v)
  exec(run_string)
```

to restore your local stack.  Maybe its better to use a list instead of a dict to preserve stack ordering.